# Ambiguous in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access'?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2010

I have already added Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access as reference and also Microsoft Access Object Library 14.0 but still getting this error.

Is this because of my Visual Studio and MS Office incompatibility or something else?

[image]

I found this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317157 but it's for v10.0 object libraries.

Comment: PIAs are obsolete since VS2010, elegantly replaced by the "Embed Interop Types" feature.  You do have to change your code, drop "Class", it is simply "Access.Application".  And remove the PIA reference, you just want the COM reference.

Comment: Thank you for the enlightening response! That's very good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have references to two different Access interop DLLs that define that class.

Delete one of those references from your project.

Comment: Thank you for the very prompt reply. I'm very grateful. Although yes there was an excess of DLL files referenced, and it was best to remove and add them again.